# Constructs in C++/Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

I have a question about the C++ Constructs(It's not an issue :) )
I am building a project for ESP controllers that have to perform tasks. The tasks are received by the ESP from HTTP Request in JSON format and I decode the JSON using ArduinoJSON.
In order to use the tasks list, and in order to be more clear I am defining Construct, containing the options. Before the request I do not know the number of tasks.

While testing I've allocated the size of the construct to: 1 `tasks tasks[1];` But have passed 4 tasks in the Setup.
The thing I do not understand is why after I serial print them I get:
1
2
3
4

I expected different behaviour, the drop of all tasks in the construct after the first one.
Can you help me understand it better?

This is the sample code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

struct tasks
{
    uint32_t id,duration;
    uint8_t nextTask,pin,interrupt,status;
    byte state,callback;  
};

byte operation;
uint8_t number_of_tasks=0;

String JSON = "{\"tasks\":[{\"task_id\":\"1\",\"pin\":\"13\",\"state\":\"1\",\"duration\":\"5\",\"interrupt\":\"0\",\"callback\":\"1\",\"status\":\"0\"},{\"task_id\":\"2\",\"pin\":\"13\",\"state\":\"1\",\"duration\":\"5\",\"interrupt\":\"0\",\"callback\":\"1\",\"status\":\"0\"},{\"task_id\":\"3\",\"pin\":\"13\",\"state\":\"1\",\"duration\":\"5\",\"interrupt\":\"0\",\"callback\":\"1\",\"status\":\"0\"},{\"task_id\":\"4\",\"pin\":\"13\",\"state\":\"1\",\"duration\":\"5\",\"interrupt\":\"0\",\"callback\":\"1\",\"status\":\"0\"}]}";
tasks tasks[1];


void setup() 
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(500);
    Serial.println();

    StaticJsonDocument<1000> doc;

    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, JSON);

    if (error) 
    {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        
        return;
    }

    for (JsonObject task : doc["tasks"].as<JsonArray>()) 
    {
        tasks[number_of_tasks].id = task["task_id"];
        tasks[number_of_tasks].pin = task["pin"];  
        tasks[number_of_tasks].state = task["state"];    
        tasks[number_of_tasks].duration = task["duration"];  
        tasks[number_of_tasks].interrupt = task["interrupt"];  
        tasks[number_of_tasks].callback = task["callback"];  
        tasks[number_of_tasks].status = task["status"];        
        number_of_tasks++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<number_of_tasks;i++)
    {
        Serial.println(tasks[i].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land.  You have an array of size 1 so you only have 1 task.  If you need to to store tasks at run time but don't know how many you'll need then you want a `std::vector<tasks>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NathanOliver mentioned in his comment you are in the undefined behavior land. As a fun fact, your code might even be unpredictable at the moment. Now it may insert the elements but once you add more code, there's a chance of it crashing etc. Those are all undefined behaviors. Now to address your problem and how you can fix it:

You can use the `std::vector<tasks>` as NathanOliver suggested. That comes with some small overhead that you might not want to have in your arduino project. But it is the safest thing you can do without having to check if you need to allocate more space.

The other option I can think of (when you know exactly how many tasks you wish to process), is to just predefine (using `constexpr`) how many tasks you wish to have i.e.:

```
constexpr int max_number_of_tasks = 2;
tasks task[max_number_of_tasks];
```

and in the loop you can do a simple bounds check and break:

```
for(JsonObject task : doc["tasks"].as<JsonArray>()) {
  if (number_of_tasks > max_number_of_tasks) {
    break;
  }
...
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: You can ofcourse go down the road of allocating more space for the next tasks. But if that's the case then STL containers are IMHO a better option.

Comment: Thank you very much Milan and NathanOliver! I will make some tests with capacity() to see how the dynamic memory is handling, but anyway the tasks are not present in 100% of the time, so when I complete them I will use shrink_to_fit(). to free up memory. The idea with std::vector<tasks> is great. In addition Milan The second approach is the one I used so far for the other part of the project. Thank you once again!

Comment: There's one downside to the way `std::vector` handles it's expansion. `std::vector` is stored in a contiguous block of memory. If you add more elements to a "maxed out" vector, it will get reallocated to the next available block of memory. This can bring potential issues both with memory and execution speed. In general if I may recommend you something I would look into books about "Real time" programming. It's concepts are heavily used in the embedded world. Good luck and glad I could help!